# Spring Boot: pruning application context for integration testing

Tags: spring-boot, junit, integration-testing

JUnit Jupiter 5.7.2 and Spring Boot 2.6.3 here. I have the following service class:

```
@Service
public class PasswordService implements PasswordEncoder {

    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private PasswordGenerator passwordGenerator;
    private CharacterCharacteristicsRule passwordCharacteristicsRule;
    private Integer minPasswordLength;

    @Autowired
    public PasswordService(
            BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder,
            PasswordGenerator passwordGenerator,
            CharacterCharacteristicsRule passwordCharacteristicsRule,
            @Value("${myapp.users.passwords.min-length}") Integer minPasswordLength) {
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
        this.passwordGenerator = passwordGenerator;
        this.passwordCharacteristicsRule = passwordCharacteristicsRule;
        this.minPasswordLength = minPasswordLength;
    }

    public String generatePassword() {
        return passwordGenerator.generatePassword(minPasswordLength, passwordCharacteristicsRule.getRules());
    }

    public String protectPassword(String plaintextPassword) {
        return passwordEncoder.encode(plaintextPassword);
    }

    @Override
    public String encode(CharSequence rawPassword) {
        return protectPassword(rawPassword.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(CharSequence rawPassword, String encodedPassword) {
        return protectPassword(rawPassword.toString()).equals(encodedPassword);
    }

}
```

I have a unit test for each method, but because its `generatePassword()` method is so important and depends so heavily on its dependencies, I also want to create an integration test for it that actually autowires/injects it with **real** instances of all of its dependencies.

My best attempt:

```
@SpringBootTest
public class PasswordServiceIT {

    @Inject
    private PasswordService passwordService;

    @Test
    public void when_generatePassword_should_generate_valid_password() {

        String password = passwordService.generatePassword();
        System.out.println(String.format("Password is: %s", password));

    }


}
```

When I run this test I am getting `Failed to load ApplicationContext` because, in my `application.yml`, I have the following:

```
server:
  port: ${SERVER_PORT}
  error:
    whitelabel:
      enabled: false
```

And when the Application Context tries to spin up, it can't inject `${SERVER_PORT}` because thats typically set by environment variable.

I don't want to hardcode it or set a default in the YAML like `${SERVER_PORT:9200}`, etc. I just don't like hardcoding configs (especially in other places, like where credentials are stored) in these YAML files.

Is there a way to "*prune*" which parts of the application context get loaded? This entire "Password Generation system" doesn't need to talk to any databases, remote services, shouldn't need a server port to start from, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create `application.yml/properties` file under `src/test/resources` to [override](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-tests-override-properties#overrideFile) the properties values for integration test cases.

The properties from `src/test/resources -> application.yml` will be loaded for only integration tests

> Now we'll override properties by putting the property file in the test resources. This file must be on the same classpath as the default one.

> Additionally, it should contain all the property keys specified in the default file. Therefore, we'll add the application.properties file into the src/test/resources:

```
src/test/resources -> application.yml

server:
  port: 9200
  error:
    whitelabel:
      enabled: false
```

If you don't want every test cases to run on `9200` port, you can specify to use random port using annotation and i would highly recommend executing tests on random port

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
```

Comment: Thanks @Ryuzaki (+1) -- what can I do about the DB connections in my `application.yml` though? Isn't Spring is still going to want me to connect to a DB since I'm using the Spring Boot JPA Starter? Is there a way to disable that or do I just use an in-memory DB (like H2) for my test application YAML? Thanks again!

Comment: i would recommend using in memory db `H2` or docker, or there are also couple of options like test containers https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testcontainers-integration-test